# Libgdx Eclipse Project Couldnt find .APK Error

Tags: android, apk, libgdx

I know there are plenty of people already asked this question but no answer solved my problem.
So basically when I try to run my project on android it says "could not find adventure.apk".

Things that i have already done:

- BuildPath>Uncheck the android
- I copied gen folder from another project
- Gave `JAVA_HOME` and `%PATH%` a path
- Cleaned Projects
- Moved codes to a clean project

Comment: Enable verbose build and see if there is useful info there: `Window > Preferences > Android > Build output > Verbose`.

Comment: Nope it doesnt even launch so no information about app on the LogCat. It just doesnt generates files and apk.

Comment: The verbose build should log the creation of the .APK (or any errors encountered).  Try enabling the verbose build as above, cleaning your projects (`Project -> Clean ...`) and then launching or rebuilding.  That should generate logs of the *build* of your app (not logs from running it).

Answer (score 1):

Open SDK Manager, and check if SDK Tools, Platform Tools and Build Tools are updated.

Comment: Exactly for that, check again :). Happened to me, first time does not show all the updates.